# Using a list access/slicing specification in a string, to access an array in Python?

Tags: python, list

I would like to have a list access (or slicing) specification in a string, such as `"[1]"` or `"[3:2]"` or `"[:-4]"` - and then apply it to an existing list in Python. Consider the following simple example:

```py
import sys

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
myargspec = None
if ( len(sys.argv) > 1 ):
  myargspec = sys.argv[1]
else:
  myargspec = ""
print( "Got command line argument: '{}'".format(myargspec) )
mylist_sliced_str = "mylist{}".format(myargspec)
print( "... attempting to access: '{}'".format(mylist_sliced_str))
mylist_sliced = eval(mylist_sliced_str)
print( "... result: {}".format(mylist_sliced))
```

Here is what the script produces with some different list access specifications on the command line:

```
$ python3 test.py
Got command line argument: ''
... attempting to access: 'mylist'
... result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

$ python3 test.py "[2]"
Got command line argument: '[2]'
... attempting to access: 'mylist[2]'
... result: 3

$ python3 test.py "[2:4]"
Got command line argument: '[2:4]'
... attempting to access: 'mylist[2:4]'
... result: [3, 4]

$ python3 test.py "[:-4]"
Got command line argument: '[:-4]'
... attempting to access: 'mylist[:-4]'
... result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Now this is all dandy fine, and it works - but it uses `eval`, which I really do not want to use.

Is there a better approach to something like this? (hopefully something that does not involve me parsing the list access specification string myself, and missing the part where regex `\d` does not match minus for negative numbers, and dealing with such errors).

Comment: So, other than using eval, there is no way that doesn't involve parsing the string yourself somehow. This is because you seem to want to use *Python source code*, so of course, you are going to need to parse this source code or dynamically evaluate it.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga - that makes sense; I guess, I was hoping that there is something in the standard library already that would do the parsing of the string properly - but I guess there isn't something like that, so I'd have to manually parse if wanting to avoid eval.

Comment: well, you have access to the actual parser, in `ast.parse`, but `[:1]` won't be a valid expression, you'd have to parse something like `dummy[:1]`. In any case, you should just design your program to take these arguments specificaly then apply them to the list.

Comment: It would be easier and safer, and not significant more difficultly for the user, to take (up to) three arguments and use them to construct a `slice` object. `python test.py 2 4` -> `mylist[slice(2, 4)]`.

Comment: I would suggest using options, so `python test.py --start 2 --stop 3` and then making the default value `None`. then you can just directly pass them to `slice`

Answer (score 1):

I just gave it a try. I think this will be helpful for you

```
import sys

myargspec = None
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
if ( len(sys.argv) > 1 ):
    myargspec = sys.argv[1]
else:
    myargspec = ""
print( "Got command line argument: '{}'".format(myargspec) )
mylist_sliced_str = "mylist{}".format(myargspec)
print( "... attempting to access: '{}'".format(mylist_sliced_str))

if not myargspec:
    mylist_sliced = mylist
else:
    nint = lambda x: int(x) if x else None
    mapped = list(map(nint, myargspec.strip("[]").split(":")))
    if len(mapped) == 1:
        mylist_sliced = mylist[mapped[0]]
    else:
        mylist_sliced = mylist[slice(*mapped)]

print( "... result: {}".format(mylist_sliced))
```